# Creating a method to subscribe to an event but fire only once

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a method that attaches adds itself to an event, and then removes itself after it was invoked.

Those are my failed attempts:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS68k.jpg

```
public Action myEvent = () => {};

void Bar(){
    
    Action invokeThenUnsubscribe = null;
    invokeThenUnsubscribe = () =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Attempt 0");
        myEvent -= invokeThenUnsubscribe;
    };

    myEvent += invokeThenUnsubscribe;
    SubscribeOnce(myEvent, () => Debug.Log("Attempt 1"));
    myEvent.SubscribeOnce(() => Debug.Log("Attempt 2"));

    myEvent.Invoke();
    myEvent.Invoke();
}

public Action SubscribeOnce( Action a, Action actionToSubscribe ) {
    Action invokeThenUnsubscribe = null;
    invokeThenUnsubscribe = () =>
    {
        actionToSubscribe.Invoke();
        a -= invokeThenUnsubscribe;
    };

    a += invokeThenUnsubscribe;
    return a;
}


public static class ActionsEx {

public static void SubscribeOnce(this Action a, Action actionToSubscribe){
    Action invokeThenUnsubscribe = null;
    invokeThenUnsubscribe = () => {
        actionToSubscribe.Invoke();
        a -= invokeThenUnsubscribe;
    };
    
    a += invokeThenUnsubscribe;
  }
}
```

I realize it's happening because, after using +=, I lose the reference to the new event.
Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve the effect I'm looking for?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What exactly is the problem? You mention you are trying something and your 'failed attempts". So how do you know they failed? What is the problem? Are you seeing an error? Is the method firing more than once?

Comment: technically, `myEvent` isn't an "event" - it is a public field; that doesn't change anything, and it should already work if the code unsubscribes *from the event/field* - but not in the bottom version, where it doesn't; suggestion, though: `public event Action MyEvent;` and `MyEvent?.Invoke();`

Comment: Something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNJHC4 ? Or more abstraction, so you can wrap some logic in it?

Comment: You suggest these are failed attempts, but the first one (that prints `Attempt 0`) *does* work.

Comment: It would be easy/perhaps more flexible to make it a SubscribeN and have an int counter for the number of times it fires, set it to whatever N is, then decrement it every time you fire, and `if(fireCounter-- > 0) event.Invoke()` - you don't need to unsubscribe per se, just don't invoke if your counter has reached 0

Comment: @JuanR My problem is that Attempt 1 and Attempt 2 are never printed. 
Attempt 0, on the other hand, is printed correctly

Answer (score 4):

When you call `SubscribeOnce`, you aren't passing a reference to "the event" (technically a field, but: semantics); instead, you're reading *the current value of the event* (field), and passing *that* to the method. At that point, it the parameter value is completely divorced from the event (field), and no change to `a` (now a captured parameter) will have any effect on the original event (field). You're only "unsubscribing" a local delegate that has nothing to do with the event (field).

To do what you'd want, you'd need to pass the *originating object* in as the parameter, i.e. something like:

```cs
public static void SubscribeOnce(this SomeType obj, Action actionToSubscribe){
    Action invokeThenUnsubscribe = null;
    invokeThenUnsubscribe = () => {
        actionToSubscribe.Invoke();
        obj.TheEvent -= invokeThenUnsubscribe;
    };
    
    obj.TheEvent += invokeThenUnsubscribe;
  }
}
```

where `SomeType` (which could be an interface) defines an `event Action TheEvent;`, with usage `this.SubscribeOnce(() => Debug.Log("Attempt 2"));` (or whatever object you want to use)

Answer (score 0):

I am not crazy about the fact that you are mixing actions with events. Instead, I would use a more object oriented approach and separate the two concepts by creating an interface to represent the subscribable objects that expose some event and then use an extension method to allow all actions to subscribe once to these objects:

```
//Delegate to handle events
public delegate void SomeEventEventHandler(ISubscribable sender, EventArgs args);

//Interface that describes an object you can subscribe to
public interface ISubscribable
{
    event SomeEventEventHandler MyEvent;
}

//Implementation of a subscribable object (base class)
public class SomeObject : ISubscribable
{
    private SomeEventEventHandler _handler;

    public event SomeEventEventHandler MyEvent 
    {
        add { _handler += value; }
        remove { _handler -= value; }
    }
    
    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        _handler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

//Extension method for actions
public static class ActionExtensions
{

    public static void SubscribeOnce(this Action action, ISubscribable subscribable)
    {
        SomeEventEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = new SomeEventEventHandler((ISubscribable subscribable, EventArgs args) => 
        {
            action();
            subscribable.MyEvent -= handler;
        });
        subscribable.MyEvent += handler;            
    }        
}

//Usage:
var obj = new SomeObject();

obj.MyEvent += (ISubscribable sender, EventArgs args) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attempt 0 (always fires).");
};

Action invokeThenUnsubscribe = () => { Console.WriteLine("Attempt 1"); };
invokeThenUnsubscribe.SubscribeOnce(obj);

Action invokeThenUnsubscribe2 = () => { Console.WriteLine("Attempt 2"); };
invokeThenUnsubscribe2.SubscribeOnce(obj);

obj.RaiseEvent();
obj.RaiseEvent();
obj.RaiseEvent();
```

Output:

```
Attempt 0 (always fires).
Attempt 1
Attempt 2

Attempt 0 (always fires).

Attempt 0 (always fires).
```

Alternatively, you can skip the action extension all together and provide this functionality as a method of the class:

```
//In class SomeObject 
public void SubscribeOnce(Action action)
{
    SomeEventEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = new SomeEventEventHandler((ISubscribable subscribable, EventArgs args) =>
    {
        action();
        subscribable.MyEvent -= handler;
    });
    this.MyEvent += handler;
}

//Usage:
var obj2 = new SomeObject();
obj2.MyEvent += (ISubscribable sender, EventArgs args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attempt 0 (always fires).");
};

obj2.SubscribeOnce(() => { Console.WriteLine("Attempt 1"); });
obj2.SubscribeOnce(() => { Console.WriteLine("Attempt 2"); });

obj2.RaiseEvent();
obj2.RaiseEvent();
obj2.RaiseEvent();
```

This produces the same output.